# Regular expression / re2 to describe "in between"

Tags: regex, re2

In google spreadsheet I have texts that has the form:

```
lorum ispsum lorum <pete@gmail.com>
```

i want to build a formula to extract the email address from this text, that is: pete@gmail.com

it sound like that would be possible REGEXEXTRACT and the re2 expression for "in between the "<" and ">" but how would that expression look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be something like this `=REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "<(.+)>")`

[image: proof]